# Displaying a single feed by passing encrypted id number on a website in PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I want to display a single feed which is stored in my database on my website. The id will be fetched from database and if there is a match in provided id then the feed will be displayed. But i don't want to disclose the id of my feed. Like if I want to access the feed having id 1,

I will have to visit the url http://example.com/feed/12345.

Where "12345" is some encrypted numerical equivalent of 1. How can this be implemented in php?

Comment: The first question here is ***why?*** What's so bad about the user knowing the meaningless numeric id "1"? If you change it to "12345", then the id for all intends and purposes is "12345". What's so much better about that?

Comment: @deceze maybe he just want to hide count of feeds in the service.

Comment: @deceze: Any idea, how twitter does it?

Comment: How Twitter does what? They have numeric ids for their tweets.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways:
1. Generate ID as a random unique string, not as auto-incremented.
2. Use http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php